# StyleCop+ SignalR naming

Tags: c#, stylecop, stylecop-plus

In our application we are using StyleCop+ and SignalR. We did name our entities SignalRUser and SignalRConnection and StyleCop+ does not like this. I could suppress the message for these entities, but our variables are named signalRUser or else.

I already added SignalR to the list of abbreviations and recognized words, but StyleCop+ still says

```
SP0100 : StyleCopPlus.StyleCopPlus : Local variable name signalRUser doesn't conform the specified style: sampleName.
```

How can I tell StyleCop+ to ignore the "misspelling"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `SignalR` to *Compound words (or abbreviations)* list it should allow `SignalRUser`, `SignalRConnection` or `MySignalRWhatever`.

However, `singalRUser` will not still be allowed, I suppose, since it's lowercase.

Alternatively, you could add just `R` to that list. In that case, any name like `myRFeature`, `signalR` or `RType` should be allowed as well.